# Family consisting of empty set and all unions of partition of a set is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am doubt with the exercises 2.7 on Oksendal SDE book. It states:

Suppose $G_1,...,G_n$ are disjoint subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\Omega = \cup^n G_i$. Prove that the family $\mathcal{G}$ consisting of $\varnothing$ and all unions of some of $G_1,...,G_n$ constitutes a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

For convenience, suppose that $n=2$ and $G_1,G_2$ are disjoint non-empty subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\Omega = G_1 \cup G_2$. If we just take $\mathcal{G}$ consisting of $\varnothing$ and all unions of $G_1$ (that is $G_1$ itself), then it seems that  $\mathcal{G}$ is not  a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ since $\mathcal{G}$ does not contain $\Omega$ ($\mathcal{G}$ only contains $\varnothing$ and $G_1$). Do I have any misunderstanding  about the exercises?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Why are you restricting ${\cal G}$ to the empty set and $G_1$???? How is that connected to the problem?

Comment: The exercise said any family consisting of $\varnothing$ and all unions of some of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is a $\sigma$- algebra. So I take some of $G_1$ and $G_2$ to be just $G_1$. I am not trying to prove the exercise, but I try to visualize the problem by simply letting $n=2$. In general, I think my setting fits the assumptions of the exercise?

Comment: You lost me. With $n=2$ the collection is $\emptyset, \Omega, G_1, G_2$. It is easy to see that $G_2 = G_1^c$ since the union is $\Omega$ and so this collection is a $\sigma$ field.

Comment: I am not quite understanding what "all unions of some of G_1,...,G_n " in the question means. For example, I think "all unions of $G_1,...,G_{n-1}$" satisfies this meaning.

Comment: It means pick some index set $I \subset \{1,...,n\}$ and form the set $\cup_{i \in I} G_i$. Take all such sets and the empty set.

Comment: All unions mean that $I$ can be any set in $\{1,...,n\}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123099/discussion-between-mnmn1993-and-copper-hat).

Comment: Yes, $I$ can be any of the $2^n$ subsets. By convention, $\cup_{i \in \emptyset} G_i = \emptyset$.

Comment: It settles my problem, thanks!